# Aspnetcore API route Template based on Host

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core

I have a set of APIs in an ASP.NET Core (.NET6) project that are exposed both internally (private) and through an API gateway. When served privately, API urls are of the form `service.internal/api/v1/resource` which is achieved with a `RouteAttribute` on the `ApiController`:

```cs
[ApiController]
[Route("api/v{version:apiVersion}/[controller]")]
public class ResourceController : ControllerBase
{
  // actions 
}
```

When accessed via our api gateway, however, the `/api/` component of the url is absent, ie. `gateway.com/v1/resource`. The gateway performs a transformation on the Url which adds in the extra path segment for the internal/proxied request.

This all works "fine" except in a few circumstances. The primary issue I'm having is with link/url generation for requests coming through the gateway. Location headers added by `CreatedAt` and link headers generated with `IUrlHelper` include the `/api/` segment of the route with the gateways hostname rendering them invalid. I also have some issues with swagger but I believe they should resolve themselves if I can solve this.

**Question**: Is there a way to make the route template dynamic based on the host name (which would not be a compile time constant, ie. from config)? For example for requests coming from `gateway.com`, the route template would be `v{version:apiVersion}/[controller]` and otherwise would be `api/v{version:apiVersion}/[controller]`?

It doesn't need to be attribute driven if there's a different way. But my understanding is that the `ApiControllerAttribute` makes attribute routing required and I wouldn't want to lose the other benefits of that.

If I can get this to work, I'd be able to update the gateway and not have it add the `/api/` segment to the proxied urls and it should remove any issues with swagger since the proper paths would be detected by the api explorer.

Unfortunately I have no idea where to start looking. I reviewed some of the routing docs but I didn't see anything that would do the job. I admit I'm out of my league here with minimal aspnetcore experience.

If it matters we are using endpoint routing:

```cs
app.UseRouting();
app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
{
  endpoints.MapControllers();
});
```

Comment: So I was able to work around this by defining a replacement `LinkGenerator` that delegates to the main version but then performs post-op to replace well known path segments only when coming through my gateway. This along with a swagger preserialize-filter solves all my issues. That said, I'm still interested in a better answer if one exists